# For a specific cell in a pandas dataframe, remove an element of a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pandas

So I'm using python 3 and importing pandas as pd, and I have a dataframe, df, for which the elements are a list of ints. I'm trying to write a function that will remove an element from a list in a specific cell of the dataframe.

what I have is:

```
def eliminate(r,c,v):
    '''for row r and column c eliminate value v'''
    df[c][r].remove(v)
```

However when i run the function it removes v from the list in every cell. I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: FWIW, generally better not to store lists inside pandas dataframes.  E.g. a columns of lists of integers is better organized into additional rows and/or columns of integers.  Your code will almost always be faster and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting and swap `c` and `r`:

```
def eliminate(r,c,v):
    '''for row r and column c eliminate value v'''
    df.loc[r, c].remove(v)
    return df
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2,3],[3,4]],
                   'B':[[4,5],[6, 3]]})

print (df)
           A       B
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5]
1     [3, 4]  [6, 3]

def eliminate(r,c,v):
    '''for row r and column c eliminate value v'''
    #another solution
    #df.loc[r, c] = [x for x in df.loc[r, c] if x != v]
    df.loc[r, c].remove(v)
    return df

print (eliminate(0,'A',2))
        A       B
0  [1, 3]  [4, 5]
1  [3, 4]  [6, 3]

print (eliminate(1,'B',3))
        A       B
0  [1, 3]  [4, 5]
1  [3, 4]     [6]
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Why would this code work if the OP's doesn't?  Isn't it more likely that the OP has put multiple references to the same list in the frame?

Comment: @DSM - ooops, I test it and you are right. Maybe type problem? I get no feedback from `OP` yet.

Comment: @DSM - Maybe OP forget `return df`

Comment: @DSM confirmed on my end.  `df = pd.DataFrame([[[1, 2]]]); df[0][0] is df.iloc[0, 0]` is `True`